# How to interpret variable.importance for an rpart object

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart, rpart

How can I interpret the values for the `variable.importance` in an `rpart` object?

```
pmodTree$variable.importance


satisfaction level    number of projects average monthly hours       last evaluation 
         2161.1501546          1140.5711855          1112.0014799          1005.2704105 
years at company         work accident promoted last 5 years            department
825.2875165            40.4288851            17.4146171             0.5501881
```

What exactly do these values mean? In the summary funtion they are scaled to add to 100. So could that be the percentage of how important they are in classifying? But what do the unscaled values tell me? Couldn't find anything useful on the internet.

**Answer:**
The values are calculate by summing up all the improvement measures that each variable contributes as either a surrogate or primary splitter. So the higher the value is, the more the variable contributes to improving the model. The variables with a scaled importance near to zero are left out of the final tree model.
Source: [1](http://www.dansteinbergblog.com/dan-steinberg/what-is-the-variable-importance-measure)

Comment: You might be better off on an R site as requests for help interpreting R output often get closed here as off-topic.

Comment: Your link to the blog entry did not come through.

Comment: Fixed it, should work now